# Bessel function of first kind orthogonality equation

Tags: orthogonality, bessel-functions

How do I show that:

$$\int_0^1{x[J_n(\alpha x)]^2dx}=\frac1 2[J_n'(\alpha)]^2$$

where $\alpha$ is a zero of the Bessel function?

Switching to $z=\alpha x$ gives:

$$\frac1 {\alpha^2}\int_0^\alpha{z[J_n(z)]^2dz}$$

But here I'm stuck. I can use integration by parts, and replace $J_n''$ from the Bessel equation when it comes up. But that introduces an additional $z^2$ term, so I get no closer to proving the equality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $u_1$ and $u_2$ satisfy the Sturm–Liouville equations
$$ -(pu_i')'+qu_i = \lambda_i w u_i $$
(we assume nothing about boundary conditions). Then
$$ \frac{d}{dx} p(u_1'u_2-u_2'u_1) = (pu_1')'u_2-(pu_2')'u_1 = (q-\lambda_1 w)u_1u_2-(q-\lambda_2 w)u_1u_2 = (\lambda_2-\lambda_1)w u_1 u_2, $$
so
$$ \int w u_1 u_2 \, dx = -p\frac{u_1'u_2-u_2'u_1}{\lambda_1-\lambda_2}. $$

In particular, $y=J_{\nu}(\alpha x)$ satisfies the equation
$$ -(xy')' + \frac{\nu^2}{x} y = \alpha^2 x y, $$
which gives us the indefinite integral
$$ \int x J_{\nu}(\alpha x) J_{\nu}(\beta x) \, dx = -x\frac{\alpha J_{\nu}'(\alpha x) J_{\nu}(\beta x) - \beta J_{\nu}'(\beta x) J_{\nu}(\alpha x) }{\alpha^2-\beta^2}, $$
and so for $\nu \geq -1/2$, the definite integral
$$ \int_0^1 x J_{\nu}(\alpha x) J_{\nu}(\beta x) \, dx = -\frac{\alpha J_{\nu}'(\alpha) J_{\nu}(\beta) - \beta J_{\nu}'(\beta) J_{\nu}(\alpha) }{\alpha^2-\beta^2}, $$
since we always have either $xJ_{\nu}(x)J'_{\nu}(x) \to 0$ as $x \to 0$ in this case. Suppose that $\alpha$ is a zero of $ J_{\nu}$, and this reduces to
$$ \int_0^1 x J_{\nu}(\alpha x) J_{\nu}(\beta x) \, dx = -\frac{\alpha J_{\nu}'(\alpha) J_{\nu}(\beta)}{\alpha^2-\beta^2}. $$
If we now let $\beta \to \alpha$ and expand
$$ J_{\nu}(\beta) = (\beta-\alpha)J_{\nu}'(\alpha) + O((\beta-\alpha)^2), $$
we obtain
$$ \int_0^1 x [J_{\nu}(\alpha x)]^2 \, dx = \frac{1}{2}[J_{\nu}'(\alpha)]^2$$
as desired.

Comment: One could also use LHR to evaluate the limit $\lim_{\alpha\to \beta}\frac{\alpha J'_\nu(\alpha)J_\nu(\beta)-\beta J'_\nu(\beta)J_\nu(\alpha)}{\alpha^2-\beta^2}$.  It is perhaps quite a bit more direct.  And the "$x$" in the expression for $\int_0^1 xJ_\nu(\alpha x)J_\nu(\beta x)\,dx$ should be "$1$".  I've edited.