# Integral involving the Bessel function of the first kind

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, bessel-functions

I'm trying to prove

$$\int_0^1xJ_n(ax)^2\,dx=\frac{1}{2}{J_n'(a)}^2$$

where $a$ is a zero of the nth Bessel function.
The furthest I am getting is substituting $z=ax$ and then integrating by parts to find

$$I=-\frac{1}{a^{2}}\int_0^az^2J_n(z)J_n'(z)dz$$

A hint I've been given is to use the fact that $J_n$ satisfies the Bessel equation but I can't find a way to do it. I'd love to see how to do it this way if possible. I know there's already another solution here  [Bessel function of first kind orthogonality equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2775829/bessel-function-of-first-kind-orthogonality-equation) but I'd like to see if it is possible to do as the hint describes?
Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: If $a$ is a zero of $J_n$ then the RHS is always zero...

Comment: Mathematica finds 
$$=2^{-1-n}t^n\Gamma\left(\frac{n+2}{2}\right){}_1\overset{\sim}{F}_2\left(\left[1+\frac{n}{2}\right];\left[1+n,2+\frac{n}{2}\right];\frac{-t^2}{4}\right)$$

Comment: @PaulEnta You are entirely right, thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: I think computing $\frac{\partial I}{\partial a}$ will help.

Comment: The solution you link does use the fact that $J_n(\alpha x)$ satisfies a differential equation, so it's not at all clear how your desired solution would differ from that.